# Why this difference of handling method ambiguity in Java & c#?

Tags: c#, java, oop

I have two classes A & B, where B is derived from A.

Both the classes have a method with same signature. They are called in the following manner in Java & c#-->

---

In case of JAVA :

```
class A
{
    public void print()
    {
        System.out.println("Inside Parent");
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    public void print()
    {
        System.out.println("Inside Child");
    }
}

class test4
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        B b1=new B();
        b1.print();
        A a1=new B();
        a1.print();
    }
}
```

This program generates the following output:-

```
Inside Child
Inside Child
```

---

In case of C# :

```
class A
{
    public void print()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Inside Parent");
    }
}

class B : A
{
    public void print()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Inside Child");
    }
}

class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        B b1=new B();
        b1.print();
        A a1=new B();
        a1.print();
        System.Console.Read();
    }
}
```

This program generates the following output:-

```
Inside Child
Inside Parent
```

### Why does the output differ ?

Comment: I think your C# code would generate a compiler warning for overriding a method in a parent class without using keyword `new` or keywords `virtual / override`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Java, methods are `virtual` by default.
In C#, methods are *not* `virtual` by default.

So, in order for the C# code to behave the same as the Java code, make the method `virtual` in the base class and `override` in the derived class.

Or, in order for the Java code to behave the same as the C# code, make the method `final` in the base class.

Comment: And don't forget the `override` keyword in the child class.

Comment: Yeah.. In java, 'Method Overriding' happens when methods with same signature reside in different classes, and the object of any of those classes can access only the latest version of that method(i.e the method of last derived class). So, method overriding in java happens explicitly..  
In c#, 'Method Overriding' never explicitly happens unless you make the base-class method as 'virtual', and it's derived class method an 'override' of it.

Comment: @Srinivas: I think you mean that method overriding in Java happens *implicitly*, i.e. without any special requirements on the code or coder. In C# on the other hand, method overriding happens *explicitly*, i.e. the coder has to *explicitly* state that he wants to override the method.

Comment: @cremor: Right. Added that to the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

In case of c# you need to make the parent method as virtual and child method as an override

```
class A
{
public virtual void print()
{
System.Console.WriteLine("Inside Parent");
}
}
class B : A
{
public override void print()
{
System.Console.WriteLine("Inside Child");
}
}
class Program
{
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
B b1=new B();
b1.print();
A a1=new B();
a1.print();
System.Console.Read();
}
}
```

Comment: yeah.. thnks for d info..

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
  A a1=new B();
```

I think here, in C# you have an example of method hiding.  Perhaps you need to explicitly declare the method as overridden (for example in java using the @Override annotation).